# Is there a tagged union/sum type in elisp? If not, what to use instead?

Tags: variables, conditionals

In many programming languages, if one wants a variable that can take a discrete number of values, one has the capacity to define the permissible values in advance, using something like an enum.

Does elisp have any functionality like that?

My use case: I'm using the same configuration file across multiple computers.  I'm reading an identifier from an environment variable, and I'd really like to store that in an elisp variable as a sum type, so that I can do something like

```
(cond ((eq which-computer home) (do-home-config))
      ((eq which-computer office) (do-office-config))
      (t (message "unknown computer")))
```

where `which-computer` is a variable that can only take the values `home` and `office`.

Is that a thing one can do in elisp?

(I don't really know what to tag this question, since apparently using the elisp tag is, like, verboten.)

Comment: If the valid values are a fixed set, but you're setting it from an arbitrary env var, then what happens when that var does not have a valid value, and how would that be different to handling unknown values with your `t` case in the `cond` expression?  What do actually *want* to happen in that scenario?  (Error?  Message?  Silently ignore it?)

Comment: n.b. I'm partly driving at the point that I would expect assigning an *invalid* value to be an **error**, but I doubt you actually want your Emacs config to **fail** to load if you happened to not have some environment variable set with a particular value.

Comment: @phils answered the question well. In a nutshell, in Lisp variables have no type; only values are typed. Your conditional code correctly tests the value of your variable. You were just lacking the use of `getenv` to get the value from the environment. Phils mentions `cl-deftype`. There's also Elisp `defcustom`, which defines the "valid" types of a variable's value, but nothing stops assigning an invalid value to it.

Comment: A `defcustom` type of `choice` comes close to defining a variable whose value should be a sum/union type. (But again, nothing prevents a value that doesn't follow the type spec.) See the Elisp manual, node [Composite Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html) for `choice`, and node [Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customization.html) for the overall chapter about `defcustom`. But such typing applies only to `defcustom` (options), not to `defvar` (unfortunately, IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Elisp variables aren't declared with a type.  You can test a variable to determine the type of its current value; but if you're using `setq` or similar to assign values, then nothing prevents you from assigning values of arbitrary types to any given variable.

`cl-deftype` and friends do allow you to define a custom type which allows a fixed set of values, and you can then use things like `cl-typep`, `cl-typecase`, `cl-etypecase`, and `cl-check-type` with that type; but I honestly don't think this is a useful complication for your particular use-case.

You can read more about these from: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(cl)Type Predicates`

Personally I'm not sure you even need to be *storing* a variable at all, if this is your sole use-case for it.

```el
(let ((computer (getenv "MY_COMPUTER_TYPE")))
  (cond ((equal computer "home") (do-home-config))
        ((equal computer "office") (do-office-config))
        (t (message "unknown computer"))))
```

If you *were* going to store a variable, I'd probably use much the same approach.  The following would result in a variable which was either `home` or `office` or `nil`.

```el
(defconst my-computer-type
  (let ((computer (getenv "MY_COMPUTER_TYPE"))
        (allowed '("home" "office")))
    (and (member computer allowed)
         (intern computer)))
  "Symbol for my computer type.")

(cond ((eq my-computer-type 'home) (do-home-config))
      ((eq my-computer-type 'office) (do-office-config))
      (t (message "unknown computer")))
```